# Spring Boot OpenFeign headers ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to create a feign client so my project can communicate with my company's microservice. I have added the required headers using the @Headers annotation but Spring seems to ignore them.
Code:

```
@FeignClient(
        name = "test-client",
        url = "https://example-api-development.dev.company.ai"
)

public interface TestClient {
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Authorization: My-Auth-Key",
            "X-TenantID: test"
    })
    @PostMapping("/")
    String sendFiles();
}
```

On the above example I am getting response code 401, unauthorized. As a workaround I can add the headers in a map and pass them as an argument like this: `@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headerMap`. Another workaround is creating a feignConfig class and adding the request headers there using a RequestInterceptor. But why is the @Headers annotation not working?

Edit: I am using Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Because the Contract that handles feign's native annotations has been replaced by spring's SpringMvcContract to handle spring's own annotations, you can use the `RequestHeader` annotation to pass header parameters.

If you must use `Headers` annotations, you can customize a SpringMvcContract bean  as below

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringMvcContract extends SpringMvcContract {

    @Override
    protected void processAnnotationOnMethod(MethodMetadata data, Annotation methodAnnotation, Method method) {
        super.processAnnotationOnMethod(data, methodAnnotation, method);
        if (methodAnnotation instanceof Headers headers) {
            data.template().headers(toMap(headers.value()));
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, Collection<String>> toMap(String[] input) {
        Map<String, Collection<String>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(input.length);
        for (String header : input) {
            int colon = header.indexOf(':');
            String name = header.substring(0, colon);
            if (!result.containsKey(name)) {
                result.put(name, new ArrayList<String>(1));
            }
            result.get(name).add(header.substring(colon + 1).trim());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```